# Spring Boot составной SELECT запрос

Tags: sql, postgresql, spring-boot, thymeleaf, model

Делаю CRUD приложение на Spring Boot с PostgreSQL и Thymeleaf. Пытаюсь при помощи конкатенации составить сложный составной SQL запрос для поиска по БД. Но в результате почему-то происходит излишняя конкатенация и некоторые участки запроса повторяются, плюс сам запрос почему-то дублируется. После одного запроса на поиск по имени или кличке в консоль помощи `System.out.println()` выводится это:

```
SELECT * FROM dogs WHERE nickname LIKE :nickname OR name LIKE :name 
SELECT * FROM dogs WHERE nickname LIKE :nickname OR name LIKE :name nickname LIKE :nickname OR name LIKE :name
```

Не пойму почему дублируется сам запрос и почему неправильно конкатенируется (во втором варианте часть запроса повторяется и если дальше продолжать выполнять запросы, то она будет только разрастаться). То есть насколько я понял один и тот же запрос почему-то гоняется по кругу.
Как результат выдается ошибка:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ОШИБКА: ошибка синтаксиса (примерное положение: "nickname")
```

Представление:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Собаки</title>
 <style>
   table { 
    width: 100%; 
    border: 4px double black; 
    border-collapse: collapse; 
   }
   th { 
    text-align: left; 
    background: #ccc; 
    padding: 5px; 
    border: 1px solid black; 
   }
   td { 
    padding: 5px; 
    border: 1px solid black; 
   }
  </style>
  
</head>
<body>
    
<div th:if="${isUserAuth}">Выйти</div>
<div th:unless="${isUserAuth}">Войти</div>
<div sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">
 <a href="/logout">Logout</a>  
</div>

<div sec:authorize="!isAuthenticated()">
    <p>Hello, guest! Please <a href="/login">Login</a> or <a href="/signup">SignUp</a></p> 
</div>

<div>Выберите сущность:
    <form method="post" action="">
        <input type="radio" id="dogChoice" value="dog"/><label for="dogChoice">Собаки</label>
        </form>
</div>
<div><form th:method="POST" th:object:"${searchRequest}" th:action="@{/search}">
    <select th:field="*{searchRequest.tableName}"> 
        <option th:value="dogs">Собаки</option>
        </select>
    <input type="text" placeholder="по имени или кличке"/ th:field="*{searchRequest.nicknameOrName}">
    
    <td>Порода:<select th:field="*{searchRequest.breed}">
                <option value=>Все</option>
                    <option th:each="breedType : ${T(com.example.demo6.entities.Dog.Breed).values()}" 
                        th:value="${breedType}" th:text="${breedType.type}"></option>
                </select>
    <td>Пол:<select th:field="*{searchRequest.gender}">
                    <option value=>Все</option>
                    <option th:each="genderType : ${T(com.example.demo6.entities.Dog.Gender).values()}" 
                        th:value="${genderType}" th:text="${genderType.type}"></option>
                </select></td>
            
    <input type="submit" value="Найти"/></form></div>
<table border="1" color="black" border-collapse="collapse">
    <tr>
        <td><b>ID</b></td>
        <td><b>Кличка</b></td>
        <td><b>Имя</b></td>
        <td><b>Пол</b></td>
        <td><b>Порода</b></td>
        <td><b>Дата рождения</b></td>
        <td><b>Щенки</b></td>
        <td><b>Добавлено</b></td>
        <td><b>Изменено</b></td>
        <td>Изменить</td>
        <td>Удалить</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <form modelAttribute="dog" th:method="POST" th:object:"${dog}" th:action="@{/}" action="#">
            <td><input type="submit" value="Добавить"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" th:field="*{dog.nickname}"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" th:field="*{dog.name}"/></td>
            <td><select th:field="*{dog.gender}">
                    <option th:each="genderType : ${T(com.example.demo6.entities.Dog.Gender).values()}" 
                        th:value="${genderType}" th:text="${genderType.type}"></option>
                </select></td>
            <td><select th:field="*{dog.breed}">
                    <option th:each="breedType : ${T(com.example.demo6.entities.Dog.Breed).values()}" 
                        th:value="${breedType}" th:text="${breedType.type}"></option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td><input type="date" th:field="*{dog.dateOfBirth}"/></td>
            <td><input type="number" th:field="*{dog.puppies}"/></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            </form>
        </tr>
        <tr th:each="dog : ${dogs}">
            
                <form id="edit" modelAttribute="dog" th:method="DELETE" th:object:"${dog}" th:action="@{/{id}(id=${dog.getId()})}" action="#">
                     
                    <td th:text="${dog.id}"></td>
                    <td th:unless="${dog.isModifying}" th:text="${dog.nickname}"></td>
                    <td th:if="${dog.isModifying}" th:text="${dog.nickname}"><input type="text" th:field="*{dog.nickname}"/></td>
                    <td th:unless="${dog.isModifying}" th:text="${dog.name}"></td>
                    <td th:if="${dog.isModifying}" th:text="${dog.name}"><input type="text" th:field="*{dog.name}"/></td>
                    <td th:unless="${dog.isModifying}" th:text="${dog.gender.type}"></td>
                    <td th:if="${dog.isModifying}"><select th:field="*{dog.gender}">
                            <option th:each="genderType : ${T(com.example.demo6.entities.Dog.Gender).values()}" 
                            th:value="${genderType}" th:text="${genderType.type}"></option>
                        </select></td>
                    <td th:unless="${dog.isModifying}" th:text="${dog.breed.type}"></td>
                    <td th:if="${dog.isModifying}"><select th:field="*{dog.breed}">
                            <option th:each="breedType : ${T(com.example.demo6.entities.Dog.Breed).values()}" 
                                th:value="${breedType}" th:text="${breedType.type}"></option>
                        </select></td>
                    <td th:unless="${dog.isModifying}" th:text="${dog.dateOfBirth}"></td>
                    <td th:if="${dog.isModifying}"><input type="date" th:field="*{dog.dateOfBirth}"/></td>
                    <td th:unless="${dog.isModifying}" th:text="${dog.puppies}"></td>
                    <td th:if="${dog.isModifying}"><input type="number" th:field="*{dog.puppies}"/></td>
                    <td th:unless="${dog.isModifying}" th:text="${dog.modifiedAt}"></td>
                    <td th:unless="${dog.isModifying}" th:text="${dog.createdAt}"></td>
                    <td><input type="button" id="toedit" value="Изменить" onclick="toEdit()" form="edit"/></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Удалить"</td>                                       
                </form>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                
       
                
        
            </tr>
 </table>
 <script>
        toedit.onclick = function()
            {
                document.getElementById('eachDog').innerHTML = document.getElementById(document.getElementById('edit').value).innerHTML;
                alert("pashet");
            };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Контроллер:

```
package com.example.demo6.controllers;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PatchMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import com.example.demo6.entities.Dog;
import com.example.demo6.search.Search;
import com.example.demo6.service.DogService;
import jakarta.validation.Valid;

@Controller
@RequestMapping
public class DogController extends AbstractController<Dog, DogService> {
    private DogService dogService;
    
    @Autowired
    public DogController(DogService service, DogService dogService) {
        super(service);
        this.dogService = dogService;
    }
    
    @GetMapping(path = {"/search", "", "/"})
    public String index(Model model, @ModelAttribute("searchRequest") Search searchRequest) {
            model.addAttribute("searchRequest", new Search());
            model.addAttribute("dog", new Dog());
            //model.addAttribute("dogs", dogService.find(searchRequest));
            return "index";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public String edit(Model model, @PathVariable("id") int id) {
        model.addAttribute("searchRequest", new StringBuilder());
        model.addAttribute("dog", dogService.findById(id));
        return "editdog";
        
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/search")
    public String search(Model model, @ModelAttribute("searchRequest") Search searchRequest) {
        dogService.find(searchRequest);
        model.addAttribute("searchRequest", new Search());
        return "redirect:";
    }
    
    @PostMapping
    public String save(@ModelAttribute("dog")@Valid Dog dog, Model model) { 
        dogService.save(dog);
        return "redirect:";
    }
    
    @PatchMapping("/{id}")
    public String update(@ModelAttribute("dog")@Valid Dog updatedDog, @PathVariable("id") int id, Model model) {    
        dogService.update(id, updatedDog);
        return "redirect:";
    }
    
    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public String delete(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
        dogService.delete(id);
        return "redirect:";
    }
}
```

Сервис:

```
package com.example.demo6.service;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate;

import com.example.demo6.Demo6Application;
import com.example.demo6.entities.Dog;
import com.example.demo6.repositories.DogRepository;
import com.example.demo6.search.Search;
import com.example.demo6.jdbctemplateaddons.DogMapper;

@Service
public class DogService extends AbstractEntityServiceImpl<Dog, DogRepository> {
    private DogRepository dogRepository;
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate npjt;
    
    @Autowired
    public DogService(DogRepository repository, DogRepository dogRepository
            , JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate, NamedParameterJdbcTemplate npjt) {
        super(repository);
        this.dogRepository = dogRepository;
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
        this.npjt = npjt;
        
    }
    
    public List<Dog> find(Search searchRequest) {
        if (searchRequest == null || searchRequest.getTableName() == null) return dogRepository.findAll(); 
            searchRequest.getQuery();
            //System.out.println(searchRequest.getNamedParameters().toString());
        List<Dog> dogs = npjt.queryForList(searchRequest.getQuery(), searchRequest.getNamedParameters(), Dog.class);//  new DogMapper());
        searchRequest.setQuery(new StringBuilder(""));;
        return dogs;
        
    }
    /*
     
    public List<Dog> find(String searchRequest, String searchBreed, String sortBy, boolean sortAsc){
        
        Sort sort = Sort.by(sortBy).ascending();
        if (!sortAsc) sort = Sort.by(sortBy).descending();
            return dogRepository.findAll(sort).stream()
                .filter(dog -> ((searchRequest == null) || (dog.getName().toLowerCase().contains(searchRequest.toLowerCase()) 
                        || dog.getNickname().toLowerCase().contains(searchRequest.toLowerCase())))
                        && (searchBreed == null || searchBreed.equals("all") || dog.getBreed().getType().contains(searchBreed)))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());                      
    }
    */

    public Dog save(Dog dog){
        return dogRepository.save(dog);
    }
    
    @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    public Dog update(int id, Dog updatedDog){
        Dog dogToUpdate = dogRepository.findById((long) id).get();
        System.out.println(dogToUpdate.toString());
        dogToUpdate.setNickname(updatedDog.getNickname());
        dogToUpdate.setName(updatedDog.getName());
        dogToUpdate.setGender(updatedDog.getGender());
        dogToUpdate.setBreed(updatedDog.getBreed());
        dogToUpdate.setDateOfBirth(updatedDog.getDateOfBirth());
        dogToUpdate.setPuppies(updatedDog.getPuppies());
        dogToUpdate.setModifiedAt(LocalDateTime.now());
        System.out.println(dogToUpdate.toString());
        System.out.println(updatedDog.toString());
        Dog savedDog = dogRepository.save(dogToUpdate);
        System.out.println("done");
        return savedDog;
    }
    
    @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    public void delete(int id) {
        dogRepository.deleteById((long) id);
    }
    
    public Dog findById(int id){        
        return dogRepository.findById((long) id).get();
        
    }


    public JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate() {
        return jdbcTemplate;
    }

    public void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }
    
    
    
}
```

Класс поиска:

```
package com.example.demo6.search;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;

import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.MapSqlParameterSource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.SqlParameterSource;

import com.example.demo6.entities.Dog;

public class Search {
        private static final StringBuilder SELECT = new StringBuilder("SELECT * FROM ");
        private StringBuilder tableName;
        private Integer id;
        private StringBuilder nicknameOrName;
        private Dog.Breed breed;
        private Dog.Gender gender;
        private Integer minPuppiesCount;
        private LocalDate dateOfBirthFrom;
        private LocalDate dateOfBirthTo;
        private OffsetDateTime dateOfCreationFrom;
        private OffsetDateTime dateOfCreationTo;
        private OffsetDateTime dateOfModificationFrom;
        private OffsetDateTime dateOfModificationTo;
        private StringBuilder orderBy;
        private boolean descDirection;
        private StringBuilder query;
        private MapSqlParameterSource namedParameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
        
        
        public Search(){
            this.descDirection = false;
            this.query = SELECT;
        }
        
        public Search(StringBuilder tableName, Integer id, StringBuilder nicknameOrName, Dog.Breed breed, Dog.Gender gender,
                Integer minPuppiesCount, LocalDate dateOfBirthFrom, LocalDate dateOfBirthTo,
                OffsetDateTime dateOfCreationFrom, OffsetDateTime dateOfCreationTo, OffsetDateTime dateOfModificationFrom,
                OffsetDateTime dateOfModificationTo, StringBuilder orderBy) {
            super();
            this.tableName = tableName;
            this.id = id;
            this.nicknameOrName = nicknameOrName;
            this.breed = breed;
            this.gender = gender;
            this.minPuppiesCount = minPuppiesCount;
            this.dateOfBirthFrom = dateOfBirthFrom;
            this.dateOfBirthTo = dateOfBirthTo;
            this.dateOfCreationFrom = dateOfCreationFrom;
            this.dateOfCreationTo = dateOfCreationTo;
            this.dateOfModificationFrom = dateOfModificationFrom;
            this.dateOfModificationTo = dateOfModificationTo;
            this.orderBy = orderBy;
            this.descDirection = false;
            this.query = SELECT;
            //this.namedParameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
        }


        public String getQuery() {
            String preparedQuery = this.fromTable(tableName).withId(id)
                 .withNicknameOrName(nicknameOrName).withBreed(breed)
                 .withGender(gender).withPuppiesMoreThan(minPuppiesCount)
                 .withDateOfBirthBetween(dateOfBirthFrom, dateOfBirthTo)
                 .withDateOfCreationBetween(dateOfCreationFrom, dateOfCreationTo)
                 .withDateOfModificationBetween(dateOfModificationFrom, dateOfModificationTo)
                 .orderBy(orderBy, descDirection).replaceLastAnd().replaceWhereIfQueryIsEmpty().query.toString();
            System.out.println(preparedQuery);
            return preparedQuery;
        }
                
        
        public Search fromTable(StringBuilder tableName) {
            if (query.indexOf(tableName.toString()) == -1)
            query.append(tableName + " WHERE ");
            return this;
        }
        
        public Search withId(Integer id) {
            if (id != null) {
            query.append("id=:id AND ");
            namedParameters.addValue("id", id);
            }
            return this;
            
        }
        
        public Search withNicknameOrName(StringBuilder nicknameOrNameLike) {
            if (nicknameOrNameLike != null && !nicknameOrNameLike.isEmpty()) {
            query.append("nickname LIKE :nickname OR name LIKE :name AND ");
            namedParameters.addValue("nickname", "%" + nicknameOrNameLike + "%");
            namedParameters.addValue("name", "%" + nicknameOrNameLike + "%");
            }
            return this;
            
        }
        
        public Search withBreed(Dog.Breed breed) {
            if (breed != null && breed.toString() != "all") {                       
                query.append("breed=:breed AND ");
                namedParameters.addValue("breed", breed);               
            }
            return this;
        }
        
        public Search withGender(Dog.Gender gender) {
            if (gender != null && gender.toString() != "all") {         
                query.append("gender=:gender AND ");
                namedParameters.addValue("gender", gender);     
            }
            return this;
        }
        
        
        public Search withPuppiesMoreThan(Integer minPuppiesCount) {
            if (minPuppiesCount != null && minPuppiesCount > 0) {
                query.append("puppies_count > :minPuppiesCount AND ");
                namedParameters.addValue("minPuppiesCount", minPuppiesCount);
            }
            return this;
            
        }
        
        public Search withDateOfBirthBetween(LocalDate dateOfBirthFrom, LocalDate dateOfBirthTo) {
            if (dateOfBirthFrom != null) {
                query.append("date_of_birth >= :dateOfBirthFrom AND ");
                namedParameters.addValue("dateOfBirthFrom", dateOfBirthFrom);
            }
            if (dateOfBirthTo != null) {
                query.append("date_of_birth <= :dateOfBirthTo AND ");
                namedParameters.addValue("dateOfBirthTo", dateOfBirthTo);
            }
            return this;
        }
        
        public Search withDateOfCreationBetween(OffsetDateTime dateOfCreationFrom, OffsetDateTime dateOfCreationTo) {
            if (dateOfCreationFrom != null) {
                query.append("created_at >= :dateOfCreationFrom AND ");
                namedParameters.addValue("dateOfCreationFrom", dateOfCreationFrom);
            }
            if (dateOfCreationTo != null) {
                query.append("created_at <= :dateOfCreationTo AND ");
                namedParameters.addValue("dateOfCreationTo", dateOfCreationTo);
            }
            return this;
            
        }
        
        public Search withDateOfModificationBetween(OffsetDateTime dateOfModificationFrom, OffsetDateTime dateOfModificationTo) {
            if (dateOfModificationFrom != null) {
                query.append("modified_at >= :dateOfModificationFrom AND ");
                namedParameters.addValue("dateOfModificationFrom", dateOfModificationFrom);
            }
            if (dateOfModificationTo != null) {
                query.append("modified_at <= :dateOfModificationTo AND ");
                namedParameters.addValue("dateOfModificationTo", dateOfModificationTo);
            }
            return this;
            
        }
        
        public Search orderBy(StringBuilder orderBy, boolean descDirection) {
            if (orderBy != null && !orderBy.isEmpty()) {
            query.append("ORDER BY :orderBy ");
            namedParameters.addValue("orderBy", orderBy);
            }
            if (descDirection) query.append("DESC"); {
                //namedParameters.addValue("dateOfCreationFrom", dateOfCreationFrom);
            }
            return this;
        }
        
        public Search replaceLastAnd() {
            if (query.lastIndexOf("AND ") != -1)
            query.replace(query.lastIndexOf("AND "), query.lastIndexOf("AND ") + 5, "");
            return this;
        }
        
        public Search replaceWhereIfQueryIsEmpty() {
            if (query.length() - query.lastIndexOf("WHERE ") <= 7)
                query.replace(query.lastIndexOf("WHERE "), query.lastIndexOf("WHERE ") + 7, "");
            return this;
        }

        public StringBuilder getTableName() {
            return tableName;
        }

        public void setTableName(StringBuilder tableName) {
            this.tableName = tableName;
        }

        public Integer getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Integer id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public StringBuilder getNicknameOrName() {
            return nicknameOrName;
        }

        public void setNicknameOrName(StringBuilder nicknameOrName) {
            this.nicknameOrName = nicknameOrName;
        }

        public Dog.Breed getBreed() {
            return breed;
        }

        public void setBreed(Dog.Breed breed) {
            this.breed = breed;
        }

        public Dog.Gender getGender() {
            return gender;
        }

        public void setGender(Dog.Gender gender) {
            this.gender = gender;
        }

        public Integer getMinPuppiesCount() {
            return minPuppiesCount;
        }

        public void setMinPuppiesCount(Integer minPuppiesCount) {
            this.minPuppiesCount = minPuppiesCount;
        }

        public LocalDate getDateOfBirthFrom() {
            return dateOfBirthFrom;
        }

        public void setDateOfBirthFrom(LocalDate dateOfBirthFrom) {
            this.dateOfBirthFrom = dateOfBirthFrom;
        }

        public LocalDate getDateOfBirthTo() {
            return dateOfBirthTo;
        }

        public void setDateOfBirthTo(LocalDate dateOfBirthTo) {
            this.dateOfBirthTo = dateOfBirthTo;
        }

        public OffsetDateTime getDateOfCreationFrom() {
            return dateOfCreationFrom;
        }

        public void setDateOfCreationFrom(OffsetDateTime dateOfCreationFrom) {
            this.dateOfCreationFrom = dateOfCreationFrom;
        }

        public OffsetDateTime getDateOfCreationTo() {
            return dateOfCreationTo;
        }

        public void setDateOfCreationTo(OffsetDateTime dateOfCreationTo) {
            this.dateOfCreationTo = dateOfCreationTo;
        }

        public OffsetDateTime getDateOfModificationFrom() {
            return dateOfModificationFrom;
        }

        public void setDateOfModificationFrom(OffsetDateTime dateOfModificationFrom) {
            this.dateOfModificationFrom = dateOfModificationFrom;
        }

        public OffsetDateTime getDateOfModificationTo() {
            return dateOfModificationTo;
        }

        public void setDateOfModificationTo(OffsetDateTime dateOfModificationTo) {
            this.dateOfModificationTo = dateOfModificationTo;
        }

        public StringBuilder getOrderBy() {
            return orderBy;
        }

        public void setOrderBy(StringBuilder orderBy) {
            this.orderBy = orderBy;
        }

        public boolean isDescDirection() {
            return descDirection;
        }

        public void setDescDirection(boolean descDirection) {
            this.descDirection = descDirection;
        }

        public MapSqlParameterSource getNamedParameters() {
            return namedParameters;
        }

        public void setNamedParameters(MapSqlParameterSource namedParameters) {
            this.namedParameters = namedParameters;
        }
        
        public void setQuery(StringBuilder query) {
            this.query = query;
        }
}
```

Comment: Ошибку с дублированием "запроса" исправил. Оказалось, что у меня просто дважды вызывался `System.out.println()`. Но вот почему участок nickname like or name like конкатенируется многократно до сих пор не пойму.

Comment: Кажется, решил вторую проблему. Она заключалась в кешировании строк в Java: по умолчанию при стандартном способе попытки создания строки сначала ищется такая строка в кэше и, если она есть, используется повторно. Чтобы обойти это, нужно создавать новую строку явно через `String.valueOf(value)` или `new String(value)`

Comment: `nickname LIKE :nickname OR name LIKE :name AND`  так нельзя писать, почитай про приоритеты операций OR и AND

Comment: Ну и вообще ручное сложение запроса - это напрашиваться на неприятности. Лучше использовать CriteriaBuilder https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-criteria-queries

Comment: Про приоритеты забыл и не дошел пока еще. Исправлю, спасибо. Про criteria builder: он сложный, я ничего там не понимаю, да и насколько я понял все равно придется создавать кучу методов и тонну кода под все возможные вариации запросов.

Comment: Вторую ошибку я не исправил оказывается.

Comment: дублирование скорее всего из-за статичкской переменной `SELECT`. Когда присваиваешь `this.query = SELECT`, то все запросы используют один и тот же буфер. Поменяй тип SELECT на String, а инициализацию на `this.query = new StringBuilder(SELECT)`

Comment: Я уже начал с помощью criteriabuilder делать. Но если вернусь обратно, то попробую, спасибо.